# When looping through jinja2 template data in js script, the length of the array passed is incorrect

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

So I returned this Python dictionary from my Python server using Flask:

```
data_dict = {
        'name' : stock_index_name[:6],
        'price' : stock_index_price[:6],
         #'dollar_change' : stock_index_dollar_change[:6],
         #'percent_change' : stock_index_percent_change[:6]
}
```

Now in my HTML, I want to loop through the arrays I passed from the server, but the length is over a 100.
I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong lol. The array prints to the console just fine, but I would expect the array length to be 5.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    let name = ('{{ data["name"] | tojson }}'); 

    console.log(name);
    console.log(name.length);        
</script>
```

As mentioned before I am expecting 5 for length, so I can iterate without having a crazy output.

Comment: `name` seems to be a string.  What if you leave out the single quotes in `let name =`

Comment: I cant believe I didn't try that, thanks